# Is the centralizer of a subgroup a stablizer in some group action?

Tags: group-theory

$G$ a group, $H\le G$, $C_G(H)$={$g\in G$: $\forall$ $h\in H$, $gh=hg$}. Is $C_G(H)$ the stablizer of $H$ in some group action $G$ on $P(G)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $K$ is any subgroup of any group $G$, then $K$ is the stabilizer of $K$ in its action by left multiplication on the left cosets of $K$ in $G$. Then, for any set $X$ with $|X|=|G:K|$, there is an equivalent action of $G$ on $X$ in which $K$ is the stabilizer of a given point $x \in X$.

Assuming that $P(G)$ denotes the power set of $G$, we have $|P(G)| > |G| \ge |G:C_G(H)|$, so the answer is yes, because we can let $G$ act trivially on any extra points of $P(G)$.

Comment: Thanks, but one more question, if G acts trivially on the extra points, is it still a group action?

Comment: The standard definition of a group action does not prohibit orbits of length $1$. That would prevent some of the standard actions, like a group acting on itself by conjugation, form being a group action.

Comment: I suspect you find my answer unsatisfactory, because you were probably hoping for an action that somehow involved the structures of $H$ and $C_G(H)$, but I can't see how to do that.